# REG QUERY combined with FOR return Half of what I need

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have a registry key created by InnoSetup during installation. This key contains two information :

- DisplayName
- QuietUninstallString

I don't know what is the full name of my Key. The only informations I have is the path :

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

and the value of the key "DisplayName" (MyApplicationName).

What I need to do, is to retrieve the "QuietUninstallString" value, which is supposed to be a path with "/SILENT" at the end of the path.

Right now I wrote this batch file :

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set tosearch=%1

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('
    REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s /f %tosearch% ^| findstr "QuietUninstallString"
') do set "value=%%a"

echo %value%
```

And I call it like this :

> test.bat MyApplicationName

Problem is, when I run this file, it return :

> "C:\Program

While I want this to be returned :

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFolder\MyApplicationName\unins000.exe" /SILENT

Is there a better way to retrieve the information with my batch file ?

Comment: Use `tokens=2,*` and `set "value=%%b"`. See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation

Comment: Thanks, I did tried with `tokens=2,*` but I forgot to edit `value==%%a` to `value==%%b`. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it ? @Magoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon what you've posted, you should be able to replace your entire code with this:

```sh
@For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query
 "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F
 "%~1" /E /D 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=2,*" %%H In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%%G" /V "QuietUninstallstring" 2^>NUL'
) Do @Echo(%%I
```

Or if the intention is to actually run the uninstall string:

```sh
@For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query
 "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /S /F
 "%~1" /E /D 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=2,*" %%H In (
    '%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%%G" /V "QuietUninstallstring" 2^>NUL'
) Do @Start "" %%I
```

Comment: Thanks, with what I wrote thanks to Magoo comment and the second part of your answer, I now have something that is better, and that works better, than what I intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use tokens=2,* and set "value=%%b". See for /? from the prompt for documentation